# Where is'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

laravel5.8
my `composer.json`

```php
"tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
```

`kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        /*
         * jwt
         */
        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
        'jwt.admin' => '\App\Http\Middleware\AdminCheck::class',

    ];
```

but 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ7QR.png)

Don't have  `GetUserFromToken.php`but if I dont't with token to request ,it will return 401, I don't known why
`config/auth.php`

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            //'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

route
`/routes/web.php`

```php
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
            //Route::get('logout','UserController@logout')->name('UserLogout');
            Route::get('profile','UserController@getAuthInfo')->name('UserInfo');
            Route::post('password/reset','UserController@resetPassword')->name('ResetPassword');
            Route::get('select','UserController@SelectUser')->name('SelectUser');
        });
```

Comment: You're using the >1.0 version of tymon/jwt with the installation directive of the 0.5 version.https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pbt3pr